# Android: Get mobile hardware info

Tags: android, mobile, hardware

I want to get the `RAM` ,`ROM` ,`CPU`,`Battery`,`Internal Storage` of my mobile device programmatically .I already get *Build ID*,*Device Name*,*Finger print* of my device. I go through many question but didn't find the solution. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

I want to get these info like this view
[image]

Comment: Check out Device Control. Its open-source and includes such information. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.namelessrom.devicecontrol https://github.com/Evisceration/DeviceControl

Answer (score 1):

I was using this on my code, so I put all:

```
Log.i("TAG", "SERIAL: " + Build.SERIAL);
Log.i("TAG","MODEL: " + Build.MODEL);
Log.i("TAG","ID: " + Build.ID);
Log.i("TAG","Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER);
Log.i("TAG","brand: " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","type: " + Build.TYPE);
Log.i("TAG","user: " + Build.USER);
Log.i("TAG","BASE: " + Build.VERSION_CODES.BASE);
Log.i("TAG","INCREMENTAL " + Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL);
Log.i("TAG","SDK  " + Build.VERSION.SDK);
Log.i("TAG","BOARD: " + Build.BOARD);
Log.i("TAG","BRAND " + Build.BRAND);
Log.i("TAG","HOST " + Build.HOST);
Log.i("TAG","FINGERPRINT: "+Build.FINGERPRINT);
Log.i("TAG","Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code segments will give most of the informations you need

```
//Ram information  
ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem;

//Internal Space
long freeBytesInternal = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsoluteFile().toString()).getFreeSpace();

//External Available space
long freeBytesExternal = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).toString()).getFreeSpace();

//This will out put whole lot of information about cpu just extract what you want
String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

Process process = pb.start();
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

//Battery information
BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager)getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
int batLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
```